# collectionMissingSeparator(0) Freddy JSON Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

So ... 
 1. JSON file :

```
{
    "image_id": "xDGMLGg3GCf5Ioiaf/OZJQ==",
    "request_id": "1509290346,180b0386-08cb-4332-9687-99009fb076c8",
    "time_used": 344,
    "faces": [
              {
              "landmark": {
              "mouth_upper_lip_left_contour2": {
              "y": 370,
              "x": 237
              },
              "mouth_upper_lip_top": {
              "y": 367,
              "x": 254
              },
              "mouth_upper_lip_left_contour1": {
              "y": 366,
              "x": 248
              }, ...
```

2. Code for Freddy Usage:

```
    var testx : String
    var testy : String

    init?(data: Data)
    {
        do
        {
            let json = try JSON(data: data)

            testx = try json.getString(at: "faces", "landmark", "mouth_upper_lip_left_contour2", "x")
            testy = try json.getString(at: "faces", "landmark", "mouth_upper_lip_left_contour2", "y")

            print("X= ",testx," and Y= ",testy,"inside of Freddy")
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

It seems like i did well , all is compiling, but ... when i'm trying to print it ... result is: "collectionMissingSeparator(0)"

Did from [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8g5F7RPY-I&t=2901s)

As i understood there should be some "id" for "at" parameter in my code ... however, landmarks are not collected by ID, so how to parse it correctly? Does anybody know?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i figured out the problem was: not enough brackets "}" in JSON query.